# Sylius: how to create my own Custom Resource with custom controller without getting "can not autowire"-exception?

Tags: symfony, sylius, sylius-resource

I'd like to create my own custom resource in a Sylius application as described [here](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.1/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/index_resources.html). After many pitfalls and errors as described blow I looked also at some Sylius plugins and found [this one](https://github.com/BitBagCommerce/SyliusCmsPlugin/blob/master/src/Resources/config/resources/block.yml), where everything works fine.

However, following Docs and such examples won't work in my cases.

I have defined the resource this way:

`resources.yml`:

```
    app.custody:
        driver: doctrine/orm
        classes:
            model: AppBundle\Entity\CustodyWallet
            form: AppBundle\Form\Type\CustodyType
            controller: AppBundle\Controller\Shop\CustodyController
```

`routing.yml`:

```
account_token_custody:
    path: /account/custody
    methods: [GET, POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: app.controller.custody:custodyAction
        _sylius:
            template: "@AppBundle/custody.html.twig"
            redirect: sylius_shop_account_dashboard
```

The CustodyController looks like this:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\CustodyWallet;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\CustodyType;
use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CustodyController extends ResourceController
{
    public function custodyAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        // .... code .....
    }
}
```

However, it results in the following error:

> Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Controller\Shop\CustodyController":
>   argument "$metadata" of method
>   "Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct()"
>   references interface
>   "Sylius\Component\Resource\Metadata\MetadataInterface" but no such
>   service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

Searching for this error sent me to this GitHub issue, where people recommend to set autowire to false for this particular Controller. So I did:

`services.yml:`

```
AppBundle\Controller\Shop\CustodyController:
    autowire: false
    public: true
```

But this way the constructor is called without any arguments:

> Too few arguments to function
>   Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct(),
>   0 passed in
>   /var/www/var/cache/dev/Container1MQRWcB/getCustodyControllerService.php
>   on line 16 and exactly 17 expected

I'm curious why a similar configuration works in the CmsPlugin which I have mentioned above but not in my case.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I don't use Sylius but what you need to do is to find out what service implements MetadataInterface and then create an alias.  That should get you past the initial autowire error at least.

Comment: thanks for reaching out @Cerad. MetadataInterface is the very first argument to ResourceController. But there are 16 more arguments, so it should be able to autowire the construct-call somehow. But how?

Comment: 16 args?  I guess that is impressive.  It depends on what those arguments are I suppose.  Maybe update your question showing the constructor for ResourceController.  It might be that you just have to list all 16 args in your service definition.  Or maybe you should not be extending it in the first place.  Good luck.  And Victor's answer below sounds reasonable.  Try it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this configuration

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.custody:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\CustodyWallet
                controller: AppBundle\Controller\Shop\CustodyController
```

Sylius will generate a few services, including the resource controller, as per [resource bundle documentation](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/services.html)

Just define the controller class and it will define the service and will wire the right contructor arguments.

In this case, it will generate a service with id `app.controller.custody`, which definition can be seen by running `php bin/console debug:container app.controller.custody`.

Then, in `services.yaml` there's this configuration

```
AppBundle\Controller\Shop\CustodyController:
    autowire: false
    public: true
```

which defines another service with id `AppBundle\Controller\Shop\CustodyController` that's not processed by Sylius.

Even if that configuration is removed, the error will still be there because there's an [automatic service loading](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#importing-many-services-at-once-with-resource) configured, here's [another example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-container-services-load-example) of it on the same page.

The solution is simple: exclude resource controllers from that import:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php,CustodyController.php}'
```

If there are many resource controllers and/or potentially more to be added, then it might be easier to put them in a common folder and add it to the exlude glob pattern, like:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php,ResourceController}'
```

Comment: Many thanks! For some reason it even works now without excluding the Controller in services.yml :)