# Duplicate a sylius product

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I try to duplicate a product. I have created a productController with a duplicate method

```
class ProductController extends ResourceController
{
    public function duplicate(Request $request, Product $product): Response
    {
        $parentCreate = parent::createAction($request);

        return $parentCreate;
    }
}
```

My routes.yaml :

```
duplicate_product:
    path: /admin/duplicate/{product}
    defaults:
        _controller: controller.duplicate_product:duplicate
        _sylius:
            template: "@SyliusAdmin/Crud/create.html.twig"
```

In my services.yaml :

```
controller.duplicate_product:
    class: MyNamespace\Controller\Admin\ProductController
    tags:
        - { name: controller.service_arguments }
```

Also added the ref to my controller in _sylius.yaml:

```
sylius_product:
    resources:
        product:
            classes:
                model: MyNamespace\Entity\Product\Product
                repository: MyNamespace\Repository\Product\ProductRepository
                controller: MyNamespace\Controller\Admin\ProductController
```

And i still got the following error :

> Too few arguments to function Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/cache/dev/ContainerW7PrxgE/getController_DuplicateProductService.php on line 25 and exactly 17 expected

Any idea of what can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

[Sylius: how to create my own Custom Resource with custom controller without getting "can not autowire"-exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59019479/sylius-how-to-create-my-own-custom-resource-with-custom-controller-without-gett#59021160)

Basicly, you have to remove from `service.yaml`

```
controller.duplicate_product:
class: MyNamespace\Controller\Admin\ProductController
tags:
    - { name: controller.service_arguments }
```

and in your `routes.yaml` you should use as controller `sylius.controller.product:duplicate`